# SDL2.0: SDL_GetWindowSurface() Returning Surface With Different Resolution Than Window

Tags: c++, window, sdl-2, surface

The problem is as follows:
I create a window with a size of 1600x900, but when I use the `SDL_GetWindowSurface()` function, the surface given has a separate resolution -- 1278x695 -- from the one given to the `SDL_CreateWindow()` function.
This works on my desktop, but when I compile it on my Surface Pro 2, I am faced with this error. 
Is there anyway I can change the resolution of the window to match that of its dimensions.
P.S. My Surface Pro 2 has a 1920x1080 resolution, and is running Windows 8.1 Pro. 
Thanks for any insight provided.

Comment: And what is the resolution of the surface you get back? Can the tablet *support* other than its native resolution?

Comment: The resolution I get back is: 1278x695. How would one test to see if it supports separate resolutions? I am running windows 8.1 pro.

Comment: Use [`SDL_ListModes`](http://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/SDL_ListModes) to get a list of possible resolutions. But I must admit that the resolution you get back seems odd, to say the least.

Comment: I don't believe my version has `SDL_ListModes`. What version would that be in? Was it deprecated in SDL2.0? Agreed. It is extremely odd. I didn't have this problem with a strictly OpenGL program I created previously.

Comment: Yes it's an SDL1 function. For SDL2 use [`SDL_GetNumDisplayModes`](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetNumDisplayModes?highlight=%28\bCategoryAPI\b%29|%28SDLFunctionTemplate%29) and [`SDL_GetDisplayMode`](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetDisplayMode). to get all possible display modes and resolutions.

Comment: The return data is as follows: 24 bpp, and 1920 x 1080.